# Stored Procedure for get using Data Table ASP.Net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, datatable

can Anyone help me to correct this code..

```
public static DataTable getCompartmentList(int module, string compID, string compDesc, string compType, string equipMake, string equipModel, string compMake, int compSize)
            {
                string cnnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TTDALConnection"].ConnectionString;
                DataTable dt = null;

                try
                {
                    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetCompartmentsList", cnn);
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "spGetCompartmentsList";

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@progid", module));

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compId", (object)compID ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compDesc", (object)compDesc ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compType", (object)compType ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipMake", (object)equipMake ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipModel", (object)equipModel ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compMake", (object)compMake ?? DBNull.Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compSize", (object)compSize ?? DBNull.Value));

                    cnn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    return dt;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
```

i have changed this code to handle the null reference Exception.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@progid", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  module);  

                if(compID == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compID);

                if (compDesc == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compDesc);

                if (compType == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compType);

                if (equipMake == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = equipMake);

                if (equipModel == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipModel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipModel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = equipModel);

                if (compMake == null)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compMake", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compMake);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compSize", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = compSize);


                cnn.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                return dt;
```

-----------------------------------------------This is the Exception After changed my code-------

An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in BLL.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not Int32 objects.
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Going to struggle helping you if you don't explain what the issue currently is with the code you have.

Comment: Maybe `dt.Load` throws exception since dt is Null

Comment: i have handle that exception

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Stefan, I have changed my content. Please refer.  Thanks

Comment: The way you have bracketed your parameters you are adding the value of the parameter to the command's parameter collection instead of the actual `SqlParameter`. You might want to break the instantiation of the parameters and their addition to the Command out on different lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly. Thanks everyone for your support and encouragements.

```
 public static DataTable getCompartmentList(int module, string compID, string compDesc, string compType, string equipMake, string equipModel, string compMake, int compSize)
            {
                string cnnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TTDALConnection"].ConnectionString;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "spGetCompartmentsList";


                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@progid", module));
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compId", SqlDbType.VarChar));


                        if (compID == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@compId"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@compId"].Value = compID;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        if (compDesc == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@compDesc"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@compDesc"].Value = compDesc;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compType", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        if (compType == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@compType"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@compType"].Value = compType;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipMake", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        if (equipMake == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@equipMake"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@equipMake"].Value = equipMake;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@equipModel", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        if (equipModel == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@equipModel"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@equipModel"].Value = equipModel;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compMake", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        if (compMake == null)
                            cmd.Parameters["@compMake"].Value = DBNull.Value;
                        else
                            cmd.Parameters["@compMake"].Value = compMake;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@compSize", compSize));
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return dt;
            }
```